# ActiveDirectory/ LDAP Authentication client package for GO Language?

Tags: go, active-directory, ldap

I am using the below nodejs module for LDAP authentication and searching user in a particular group. I want to do similar for my GO program but i am having a hard time finding the right module. I definitely tried google but not coming across a decent stable module for GO lang. Please advise ?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory

Comment: https://github.com/jbcrail/ldap, https://gist.github.com/sfreiberg/3372371

Answer (score 3):

You might wanna try this module https://github.com/go-ldap/ldap